# Error while trying to write a csv with partitionBy in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe which I want to partition by year, month, and day based on the existing Date column. Finally I want to write the partitioned csv to some directory.

But while writing to directory it throws the next exception when I am calling the partionBy() function. When using coalesce() instead I was able to write to the directory as expected.

Below is the code snippet for pyspark version 2.3

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
df1 = flights.select("airlines","date")\
                    .withColumn('year' , func.year(flights["date"]))\
                    .withColumn('month' ,func.month(flights["date"]))\
                     .withColumn('day' ,func.dayofmonth(flights["date"]))\
                    .drop("date")

df1.show()
```

Output

```
+--------+----+-----+---+
|airlines|year|month|day|
+--------+----+-----+---+
|   19805|2014|    4|  1|
|   19805|2014|    4|  1|
|   19805|2014|    4|  1|
|   19805|2014|    4|  1|
|   19805|2014|    4|  1|
|   19805|2014|    4|  1|
```

With coalesce() it is able to write to the directory but i need files partitioned based on the year, month and day

```
outputPath = "C:\\Users\\krishna.kanta.mitra\\Desktop\\DataSetForSpark\\mydata3.csv"
df1\
    .coalesce(1)\
    .write\
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
    .mode("overwrite")\
   .save(outputPath)
```

While writing to a directory based on the partitonBy() it throws Py4JJavaError

```
outputPath = "C:\\Users\\krishna.kanta.mitra\\Desktop\\DataSetForSpark\\mydata3.csv"
df1\
    .write\
    .partitionBy("year", "month", "day")\
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
    .mode("overwrite")\
   .save(outputPath)
```

This throws the below error while writing to a directory.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-db741623fc5d> in <module>()
      1 outputPath = "C:\\Users\\krishna.kanta.mitra\\Desktop\\DataSetForSpark\\mydata3.csv"
----> 2 df1    .write    .partitionBy("year", "month", "day")    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")    .mode("overwrite")   .save(outputPath)

C:\NiFI\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    703             self._jwrite.save()
    704         else:
--> 705             self._jwrite.save(path)
    706 
    707     @since(1.4)

C:\NiFI\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\NiFI\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

C:\NiFI\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o510.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 16.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 16.0 (TID 36, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741502: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStreamWriter(CodecStreams.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CSVFileFormat.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(CSVFileFormat.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask$$newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:511)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:546)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:527)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:527)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    ... 8 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1651)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1639)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1638)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1638)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1872)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1821)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1810)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:194)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741502: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStreamWriter(CodecStreams.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CSVFileFormat.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(CSVFileFormat.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask$$newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:511)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:546)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:527)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:527)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Hello @Krishna what happens if you combine both coalesce and partitionBy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with small dataset it worked for me as i was using Spark Standalone with minimal configurations.

```
outputPath = "C:\\Users\\krishna.kanta.mitra\\Desktop\\DataSetForSpark\\mydata8.csv"
df1\
    .write\
    .partitionBy("year", "month", "day")\
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
    .mode("overwrite")\
    .save(outputPath)
```

So this created the partition based on the year month and days.

[Screen Shot Of Directory based on the columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b41VJ.png)

```
outputPath = "C:\\Users\\krishna.kanta.mitra\\Desktop\\DataSetForSpark\\mydata7.csv"
df1\
    .coalesce(1)\
    .write\
    .partitionBy("year", "month", "day")\
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
    .mode("overwrite")\
    .save(outputPath)
```

Instead of coalesce we can go for repartition() as coalesce can only decrease the partition and can be some times slow and be error prone when we have huge data set then repartiton() and partitonBy() will split the files based on the partition of the columns you have specified.

```
outputPath = "C:\\Users\\krishna.kanta.mitra\\Desktop\\DataSetForSpark\\mydata6.csv"
df1\
    .repartition("year", "month", "day")\
    .write\
    .partitionBy("year", "month", "day")\
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
    .mode("overwrite")\
    .save(outputPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Windows, but your output path has to be a directory, unless you have just one file like you did on `coalesce(1)`. You can see in the stack trace that Spark fails to create the output path.

Comment: Yes it was not able to create the tasks as i was using spark standalone it worked with small data set.